# Run wp_query based on IDs found in array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a session array (`$_SESSION['recently_viewed']`) which currently outputs the following:

`array(3) { [0]=> int(635) [1]=> int(643) [2]=> int(474) }`

`635`, `643` and `474` are the `IDs` of posts in my custom post type called `accessories`.

I'm trying to display posts that are part of this array, but unsure how to do this logically.

So far I have:

```html
<?php
global $post;

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'accessories',
  'p' => $_SESSION['recently_viewed'], // something like this, but logically correct
  'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if($query->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    echo the_title();
  endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the the resulting array in the post__in parameter of the WP_Query.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'accessories',
  'post__in' => $_SESSION['recently_viewed'], 
  'post_status' => 'publish',
);
```

But you may need to restructure the $_SESSION['recently_viewed'] and make sure that it is a valid array. If it is valid already, then the query above should work without problem.

More info in the documentation.

// https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters